# Can't use handlebars variable twice in each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm quite new to ember.js and handlebars and I'm trying to iterate through an array in my template.

```
<select name="district" id="select-district">
   {{#each districts}}
   <option value={{name}}> {{name}} ({{count}})</option>
   {{/each}}
</select>
```

Is there anything I am missing? Everything works fine when I remove the second variable *name* inside the loop. It seems like there is a problem in using a variable twice inside the loop.

The error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html for your selector.  Additionally for the future, when looping you shouldn't be using the context switching version of `each`, that's being deprecated.  Instead use

```
{{#each d in districts}}
  {{d.name}} ...
{{/each}}
```